# td.click doesn't fire in jQuery

Tags: jquery, click, html-table

I have this table:

```
<table>
    <tr class="tools">
        <td id="dataMenuItem">
            <img src="./view/images/database.png" /><br />
            Data</td>
        <td>...
```

And this jQuery-Source:

```
$('#dataMenuItem').click(function() {
  alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});
```

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works here.  See [example](http://jsbin.com/apotu3/edit).  Have you tried to validate your HTML to make sure there are no issues there?

Oh, and are you applying the click handler within a domready event?  jQuery provides a shortcut for it like so:

```
$(function() {
    // Code to run when DOM is ready.
    $('#dataMenuItem').click(function() {
        alert('Handler for .click() called.');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In my testing, it does.

http://jsfiddle.net/HTxf2/

Tested in OSX (Chrome, Firefox) and Win (IE8)

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me...

DO you have it in a

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

block?